# BQ new DTS schema - lack of link between keyword and query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

previously we were able to tell which keyword was triggered by a certain query by combining  p_ads_Keyword and p_ads_SearchQueryStats.
On 24.04.2023 a new schema is to be introduced [based on APIv12] and the link between these tables/concepts is missing.

I'm pretty sure there has to be a way to link these as as this view is still available [https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v13/search_term_view]

I've reviewed [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/google-ads-transformation) yet I was not able to identify a suitable substitution that would deliver the same output.